# jqgrid ajax mvc json

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have a json object - so something like:

```
"data : "", status : 1"
```

where data is a huge string, be put in a jqgrid? 
I tried:

```
datastr: data, datatype: "jsonstring"
```

and the jqgrid doesn't get populated with the data..

I have an ajax call. So in my controller I will have :

```
public JsonResult Execute() 
{
  var response = (new {data = data, status =1}); 
  return this.Json(response)
}
```

and I get the correct data, but I don't know if it's possible to populate the jqgrid with this data, because it doesn't work..
Thanks!

Comment: I found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611720/how-to-return-a-mvc-view-to-a-ajax-json-post and it looks like is not possible, but I need to have an ajax call and whatever data comes back to put it in a jgqrid..